# Customize redis commands using C

Tags: c, redis

which is the best way to write custom redis commands? Which is the preferred language?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by custom redis commands?

Comment: @VarunMadiath Redis is an open-source, networked, in-memory, key-value data store with optional durability

Comment: It is written in ANSI C, this should give you some clue :)

Comment: @VarunMadiath I have some requirement, that i can't implement with existing redis commands. So want to know procedure to create my own command for redis. Is there any way to write my custom cmds in C for redis.

Comment: I'm familiar with what redis is, I'm unfamiliar with what OP meant by custom commands.

Comment: See "Customizing Redis Pubsub for message persistence" - http://abhinavsingh.com/customizing-redis-pubsub-for-message-persistence/

Comment: If you want to use C, I'd look in to the newly released [Redis Modules](http://antirez.com/news/106)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis supports 'custom commands' via LUA scripts executed using eval(). See http://redis.io/commands/eval

Comment: thank u, can i do customization in C language / in java.

Answer (score 0):

While it's possible to fork the redis code and add your own functionality to it, I'd suggest that only as a last resort. If you'd simply like redis to perform some sort of scripted activity you could look into using the lua interpreter built into redis.

[Lua EVAL command documentation](http://redis.io/commands/eval)

Comment: Can i do customization in C language or in java.

Comment: You can, fork the source code and customize there, like I said that should be the last resort.